# How can I prevent the safari redirect when using UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "myLink")!)

Tags: swift, macos

I want the app to open a social media app (i.e. Facebook), but if the user does not have the app installed, I would rather redirect them to a separate part of the app (webView, to stay in the app). I have tried a few different ways and done some research but haven't found a solution. Is this possible yet? I apologize in advance if my code isn't perfect!

```
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "myLink")!) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "myLink")!)
    } else {
        // If Facebook App is not installed, open WebView with Facebook Link
        self.parent?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "myLink", sender: self)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you added this to your info.plist?

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
 <array>
 <string>fb</string>
 </array>
```

Comment: I have added this, but if the app is installed, it opens and works perfectly, but if the app is not installed it still redirects to safari rather than what I would like it to redirect to.